# Is it possible to clear shared preference using cache memory & if yes then how to clear it?

Tags: android

In android, is it possible to delete data in shared preferences by clearing data in cache memory? if yes then what is happens & if not then why?

Answer (score 4):

Clearing an app's cache does not clear the settings. The settings data (including shared preferences) is stored in a different place than the app's cache. You need to "clear data" to clear out the shared preferences. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5744104/535871), for instance, for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Using SharedPreferences.Editor clear () and commit() will remove all values from the preferences. Do you mean this?

Comment: I mean Shared Preferences or Cache memory are any relation to clear the data in shared preference any use of cache memory in data handling in Shared Preference. & thank for answer